# Convert string to char textbox

Tags: c#, char

I need to send the data to the serial port in Char I have tried

`textbox1.Text[0]`

`Convert.Tochar(textbox1.Text);`

so basically `serialPort1.WriteLine(textBox1.Text)`; must be sent in char

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
    serialPort1.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
    textBox1.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: have you read up on the `char` datatype?

Comment: Imagine you a have a basket large enough to hold exactly one apple. You have a lot of apples and you are trying to put them all into that one basket.

Comment: the thing is I am only gonna send a 0 or 1 in the textbox but for my arduno to read the 1 or 0 it must be in char format

Comment: it cant read it as a string it needs to read it as char

Comment: Did you try Convert.Tochar(textbox1.Text[0])? And it should be Convert.ToChar(textbox1.Text[0])

Comment: ok will try it quic

Comment: tried it still not giving me te output in char

Comment: i can upload the code to my dropbox and post the link

Comment: Here is the whole thing im using as a test 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hSZ0JI_lzomcbThwFNOs8c_I1IJPwh4O

Answer (score 3):

The [`SerialPort.WriteLine` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.writeline?view=netframework-4.7.2) in the `System.IO.Ports` namespace is declared as

```
public void WriteLine (string str);
```

So I'm not sure why you think you need to pass it a `char`. Maybe it helps to set the encoding

```
serialPort.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
```

Comment: Omg im dumb thank you  so much this solves the problem

Comment: @CataclysmFormatGaming - What was the encoding set to?

Comment: Encoding was default so I guess it was set to string or int32 so when I sent the 1 to the serial port which was supposed to turn on the LED nothing happened and now after I set the Encoding to ASCII it works 100%

Comment: C# chars are 16 bit. So, probably 2 bytes were sent per `char.

Comment: Thanx again for the help Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
serialPort1.Write(new [] { textBox1.Text == "1" ? '1' : '0' }, 0, 1);
```